# mismatch in the regular expression - Tcl script

Tags: tcl

In the file i want to fetch some information using regular expressions, but it's giving me some wrong data.

where **$line** is:

```
  + ROUTED M12 10000 + SHAPE STRIPE ( 22636 * ) ( 41810 89000 )
```

Pov: instead of **ROUTED** Some lines consist of **FIXED, COVER, SHIELD**

the regex and some code what i wrote

```
if {[string match {*ROUTED*|*FIXED*|*COVER*|*SHIELD*} $line]} {

set RE {(\s*\+\s*(ROUTED|FIXED|COVER|SHIELD)[^(]+\(\s*)([^\s()]+)\s+([^\s()]+)\s*\)\s*\(\s*([^\s()]+)\s+([^\s()]+)\s*\)}
        
if {[regexp $RE $line -> match1 Vxx Vxy Vyx Vyy]} {
        set match1 $match1
        set Vxx  $Vxx
        set Vxy  $Vxy
        set Vyx  $Vyx
        set Vyy  $Vyy
puts $match1
puts $Vxx
puts $Vxy
puts $Vyx
puts $Vyy
}
}
```

where this giving me output as

```
+ ROUTED M12 10000 + SHAPE STRIPE (
ROUTED
22636
*
41810
```

where my expected result is

```
  + ROUTED M12 10000 + SHAPE STRIPE (
22636
*
41810
89000
```

what's the wrong in the code can anyone debug my code?

Comment: I noticed you have used `|` in `string match` .  That's not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I find your regex very difficult to read and maintain.

If each line you parse meets the requirements of a Tcl proper list, then try this alternative that doesn't rely regular expressions, but only positions in a list.

```
if {[lindex $line 1] in {ROUTED FIXED COVER SHIELD}} {
    if {[llength $line] ==15} {
        foreach i {8 9 12 13} {
            puts [lindex $line $i]
        }
    }
}

--> 22636
    *
    41810
    89000
```

Another alternative is the `scan` command:

```
scan $line "+ %s %s %s + %s %s ( %s %s ) ( %s %s )" status layer len type1 type2 Vxx Vxy Vyx Vyy
if {$status in {ROUTED FIXED COVER SHIELD}} {
    puts $Vxx
    puts $Vxy
    puts $Vyx
    puts $Vyy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `(ROUTED|FIXED|COVER|SHIELD)` to be matched as a group of alternatives but *not* reported as a sub-match.  Try using `(?:ROUTED|FIXED|COVER|SHIELD)` - see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M16

Comment: Either that or do an extra match variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if {[string match {*ROUTED*} $line] || [string match {*FIXED*} $line] || [string match {*COVER*} $line] || [string match {*SHIELD*} $line]} {
        puts $line

        set RE {(\s*\+\s*(FIXED|ROUTED)[^(]+\(\s*)([^\s()]+)\s+([^\s()]+)\s*\)\s*\(\s*([^\s()]+)\s+([^\s()]+)\s*\)}

    
            if {[regexp $RE $line -> match1 match2 Vxx Vxy Vyx Vyy]} {
```

the regular expression is correct but there is a change in if condition and it will work as per my requirement.
thanks for the effort.